# Passing uint8array to function

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, uint8array

I am trying to generate a excel file using fetch api and readable streams. I am trying to pass `Uint8Array` i am getting from `reader.read()`and create a buffer object from it and pass it to my writeable stream, but when i pass the array to `Buffer.from` i get the error

`The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received an instance of Object`

Below is the relevant part of my code.

I am using `node.js` & i checked in console the `typeof value` is `Uint8Array`

page here is

```
    const page = await browser.newPage(); //puppeter
```

```
let fn = `writeToStream_${Date.now()}`;
await page.exposeFunction(fn, async (body, done) => {
 let buffer = Buffer.from(body);
 await writeStream.write(buffer);
});

const fetchDataResp = await page.evaluate(async (fn, fetchUrl) => {
 const fetchPromise = fetch(fetchUrl);
 const stream = await fetchPromise;
 let reader = stream.body.getReader();
 const decoder = new TextDecoder();
 while(true) {
  const {done, value} = await reader.read();
  if (done){
   break;
  }
  await window[fn](value, false);
 }
 await window[fn]("", true);
},fn,fetchUrl);
```

what's the correct way to pass Uint8Array?

Thanks.

Comment: What is `page`, what framework are you using there? Have you debugged to check what kind of object `value` actually is?

Comment: @Bergi, i have updated the question just now. the value is `Uint8Array` object and i am using node.js

Comment: @opensource-developer It was clear that you run this code with nodejs from the tags that you used, but what `page` (and especially its methods) is or what library it comes from is still missing. Also, *how* did you check the type of that object, and which console did you use?

Comment: @Bergi, ah my bad, have updated the question again, hopefully with relevant information now :P

Comment: Ah, I suspected something like that. I'm pretty certain the problem is that you are passing an `Uint8Array` that was created in the browser realm to a function that expects an `Uint8Array` from the nodejs realm. The only thing I don't quite understand why it doesn't recognise it as an array-like object.

Comment: Also, why are you using puppeteer at all here? It seems all you want to do is to download a file and write it into a stream. No need to involve a browser there, just do the whole http request in nodejs.

Comment: @Bergi, i have a url which needs an active session and the link does not support cross domain downloads, that's what i need do not in the browser context, get data pass it to my node js function and create a file from there

Comment: Just use `page.evaluate` to extract the session details then, and still do the request from nodejs. The server cannot distinguish this.

Comment: that's would be really great, not sure how do i do that though. in case you have some examples or know how to do that, can you please share

Comment: but wouldn't the `host` parameter be not different when fetching the link from node v/s the browser context?

Comment: a) find out what constitutes a "session" for that server (most likely a cookie) b) exfiltrate that from the browser (or even establish the session, i.e login, from nodejs) c) use `request` or a similar package to send the request with the necessary headers d) pipe it into your `writeStream` … profit! :P

Comment: @opensource-developer The `Host` is the target url. No, it won't be different. As a client, you have complete control over the http request, you could emulate exactly what the browser sends if necessary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225828/discussion-between-opensource-developer-and-bergi).

Comment: thanks @Bergi this is very helpful, let me try this approach

Comment: @Bergi, ah i remember now, i had faced cross origin request error when trying to do this earlier but let me check again

Comment: @Bergi, i tried your approach but i get excel in invalid.

Comment: @Bergi, i have created another question for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65254633/node-js-fetch-pipe-with-excel-not-working. if possible can you please check and help

Answer (score 2):

I think this is due to the serialization issue. As stated in the [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args):

> If the function passed to the `page.evaluate` returns a non-[Serializable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description) value, then `page.evaluate` resolves to `undefined`. DevTools Protocol also supports transferring some additional values that are not serializable by `JSON`: `-0`, `NaN`, `Infinity`, `-Infinity`, and bigint literals.

Typed arrays seem serialized as objects:

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(new Uint8Array([11, 12, 13])));
// {"0":11,"1":12,"2":13}
```

You can try to transfer typed arrays as common arrays and then re-convert them:

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

try {
  const [page] = await browser.pages();

  await page.goto('https://example.org/');

  const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return Array.from(new Uint8Array([11, 12, 13]));
  });
  console.log(new Uint8Array(data));
} catch(err) { console.error(err); } finally { await browser.close(); }
```

Comment: That makes sense. I wouldn't have expected puppeteer to use plain old dumb JSON for serialisation though - the [structured cloning algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm) would've been a much more sensible choice.

Comment: I think JSON is mentioned for simplicity, its algorithm is a bit more advanced but close enough.

Comment: However, it seems the advanced additions are for primitives only: https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Runtime/#type-UnserializableValue