# Node.js: Fetch + pipe with excel not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

I am trying to read the contents of excel and write it into another excel. But may be i am missing something. here is relevant part of my code

```
      await fetch(fetchUrl)
        .then(
          res =>
          new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const dest = fs.createWriteStream("./text.xlsx");
            res.body.pipe(dest);
            res.body.on("end", () => resolve("it worked"));
            dest.on("error", reject);
          })
        )
        .then(x => console.log(x));
```

I get the following alert if i try to open the file

```
Excel cannot open the file ’text.xlsx’ because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify 
that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.
```

Any help as to what i am missing will be really great. Thanks.

Comment: Which `fetch` library are you using in node?

Comment: Did you try opening the downloaded file with a (hex?) editor (instead of excel) to see whether it contains the expected content? Try downloading a simpler (text only) file first. Does it get corrupted as well?

Comment: this one https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch. Yes, looks the i am missing setting something when calling fetch. if i get the link and access it via the broswer i am able to download the file. But if i do it via fetch i get html content which looks like sign in page

Comment: Well you don't seem to be sending any headers that would indicate to the server you're logged in.

Comment: If you can download the file just fine in the browser, use the devtools, go to the network panel, look for the request, and (in Chromium) you can "Copy as Node.js fetch" the statement that you'll need to send the equivalent request from your program.

Comment: you are the best, thanks @Bergi :D